# $http requests in AngularJS resulting in 400 error

Tags: angularjs, youtube-api

My `$http` request to the YouTube API in AngularJS is resulting in a 400 error. I seem to be placing all the requirements for the API.

```
angular.module('video-player')
  .service('youTube', function ($http) {
  this.search = (options) => {
    $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
      part: 'snippet',
      key: myKey,
      maxResults: options.max,
      q: options.query,
      videoEmbeddable: 'true',
      type: 'video'
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log('success');
    }, function (response) {
      console.log('failed');
    });
  }
});
```

Options:

```
var defaultSearch = {
  key: myKey,
  max: 5,
  query: 'kitten'
};

youTube.search(defaultSearch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http request in angular wants to see the data displayed as 'param'.